# Spring Boot Security custom login page doesn't load

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a custom login page on my Spring project, but when I run the project and try to access the login page, I get the following error:

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Oct 01 04:43:26 BRT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).**

Here are the files:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**TemplateController.java**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TemplateController {

    @GetMapping("login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("courses")
    public String getCourses() {
        return "courses";
    }
}
```

**ApplicationSecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable() 
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "index", "css/*", "js/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("api/**").hasRole(CUSTOMER.name())
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/courses", true)
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
    }
```

The login.html is located in a folder called **templates**, inside of **resources** (default folder on Spring project), and it seems to be working fine, since its view is displayed Visual/Source on Eclipse.

Does anybody know what may be causing this error??

Comment: Have you tried disable the security config to see if the problem occurs then?

Comment: I enabled csrf, but I still get the error.

Comment: At what point do you get the error? When you access the login page or when you submit the login form?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana when I try to access the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, guys. I just moved the **TemplateController.java** to **com.example.demo.controller** package. Now it runs perfectly!

But thank you everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the html file like this into the code:

```
.antMatchers("/overview", "/employees/*",
                        "terminal/*", "/user/*", "/create").permitAll()
```

Those are all html pages from my own project, I had the same issue and with adding them like this the security did not interfere with the mapping.So you need to include your own html page files, then they are accessible through your system. At least that was what worked for us in our project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).